# creating a json object with variable fields

Tags: javascript, json, morris.js

I am currently trying to use morris.js to create a graph. I am given one JSON object and need to make it look like another. Morris.js needs an array to look like this

```
var day_data = [
        {"period": "2012-10-01", "licensed": 3407, "sorned": 660},
        {"period": "2012-09-17", "licensed": 3171, "sorned": 660},
        {"period": "2012-09-16", "licensed": 3171, "sorned": 676},
        {"period": "2012-09-15", "licensed": 3201, "sorned": 656},
        {"period": "2012-09-10", "licensed": 3215, "sorned": 622}
        ];
```

here is the link if the object appears confusing. It should be a shortened version of the first graph's data on their site http://oesmith.github.com/morris.js/
. Its pretty simple, period is the x coordinate, and licensed and sorned are y coordinates for their corresponding lines.

Here is the data I am given

```
var trendline = {"command":[
    {"keyValuePairs":["2012-08-10 22:00:00|1884978","2012-08-10 21:00:00|3135378","2012-08-10 18:00:00|2541438","2012-08-09 20:00:00|647082","2012-08-10 19:00:00|3194772","2012-08-09 16:00:00|2782140","2012-08-10 20:00:00|3669924"],
    "keyword":"Obama"},
    {"keyValuePairs":["2012-08-10 22:00:00|1884978","2012-08-10 21:00:00|3135378","2012-08-10 18:00:00|2541438","2012-08-09 20:00:00|647082","2012-08-10 19:00:00|3194772","2012-08-09 16:00:00|2782140","2012-08-10 20:00:00|3669924"],
    "keyword":"Romney"}]}
```

I need to extract all the data from keyValuePairs and associate it with its keyword so looks like the first array

```
{"period": "2012-10-01", "Obama": 1884978, "Romney": 1884978},
 ...
 ...
```

I know to get the data from the trendline JSON object but i don't know how to construct a new JSON object that the morris.js plugin could use. More specifically i don't know how to create a JSON object using variables.

```
trendline.dog = [cat];
```

Will create a json object with the field dog set to the value cat. However, i need to take each keyword(obama,romney...etc) and have a field associated with it and set a value to it. Since i don't know the number of fields or what their names are, I don't know how to create this object.

Assume I cannot change the way I am given data as I do not write that part. Also I could be given only two keywords (obama/romney) like in my example or i could be given any number of keywords for the y-values.

Sorry for the long length. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What would be the final data for the `trendline` object? It's a little bit confusing how `{"period": "2012-10-01", "Obama": 1884978, "Romney": 1884978}` is extracted from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your Christmas present.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var trendline =
    {
        "command": [
        {
            "keyValuePairs":
                [
                "2012-08-10 22:00:00|1884978",
                "2012-08-10 21:00:00|3135378",
                "2012-08-10 18:00:00|2541438",
                "2012-08-09 20:00:00|647082",
                "2012-08-10 19:00:00|3194772",
                "2012-08-09 16:00:00|2782140",
                "2012-08-10 20:00:00|3669924"
                ],
            "keyword": "Obama"
        },
        {
            "keyValuePairs":
                [
                    "2012-08-10 22:00:00|1884978",
                    "2012-08-10 21:00:00|3135378",
                    "2012-08-10 18:00:00|2541438",
                    "2012-08-09 20:00:00|647082",
                    "2012-08-10 19:00:00|3194772",
                    "2012-08-09 16:00:00|2782140",
                    "2012-08-10 20:00:00|3669924"
                ],
            "keyword": "Romney"
        }]
    }
var cmd = trendline.command,
    day_data = [],
    split,
    date,
    num,
    obj;
//
for (var i = 0; i < cmd.length; i++) {
    //
    if (i == 1) { break; };
    //
    for (var ii = 0; ii < cmd[i].keyValuePairs.length; ii++) {
        //debugger
        split = cmd[i].keyValuePairs[ii].split('|');
        date = split[0].substring(0, split[0].indexOf(' '));
        num = split[1];

        obj = {};
        obj['period'] = date;
        //Can 1
        obj[cmd[i].keyword] = num;
        //
        split = cmd[i + 1].keyValuePairs[ii].split('|');
        num = split[1];
        //Can 2
        obj[cmd[i + 1].keyword] = num;
        //
        day_data.push(obj);
    };
};
```

Comment: I'm not at my work but i've looked through this and it seems to be good. Thanks for the present :)